# PHP send multiple values with option tag

Tags: php, html, sql

Sorry for the NOOB question, but hey im learning and have found stackoverflow to be of tremendous help to me, so first of all thank you to every contributor on this site

**The Question**

As the questions title suggest I want to know if it is possible to send multiple variable values from PHP in the Select option tag

**Example**

Say I have something like this

```
 echo '<option value="'.$row['Rating'].'">'.$row['Player'].'</option>';
```

Is it possible to include $row['Player'] in the value field TOGETHER with $row['Rating'] which is allready in the value field?

**I.E.**

Can I do something like this?
*Obviously the code below is wrong, but just serves as an examply of what I am trying to do*

```
 echo '<option value="'.$row['Rating'].'&&'.$row['Player'].'">'.$row['Player'].'</option>';
```

Comment: sure...you can use string concatenation to make that value whatever you want.

Comment: The code at the end looks fine to me. Why is it obviously wrong?

Comment: How is your option list created? If you send the player could you not derive the rating? If you're trying to rate them, why not send the player in another field?

Comment: @Barmar because I when I inspect the code when opening it in my browser I get the Rating and The Player name (which is what I want) but the && is included I suspect there is an error with my  string concatenation

Comment: Yes you can do this, but your need to do this would suggest some flaw in how you are structuring or working with your data.  Perhaps you should be using some sort of row ID here instead, assuming you are populating this from a database.

Comment: Of course the `&&` is included. What's wrong with that? You need some delimiter between the player and rating, and that's as good as anything else. In the server you can split them up with `explode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value to:

```
$row['Rating'].'&&'.$row['Player']
```

Then, when you get the data, use:

```
$both = explode('&&',$_POST['select_name']);
```

And `$both` will be an array with both values.  Obviously, you would need to replace `select_name` with the actual name of the select though.

Then, if you wanted a third value, you could go ahead and add that too:

```
$row['Rating'].'&&'.$row['Player'].'&&'.$row['other']
```

*Keep in mind that this assumes that there are no `&&` in your variables.  If there will be `&&`, you will need to use another symbol or symbols to separate the values.*

Comment: Something other than a comma, like `&&` as in his question?

Comment: True... A comma was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could send values like that, but it would be one big value. You would have to `explode()` the value if you want to use it in other code.

For example:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['Rating'].'&&'.$row['Player'].'">'.$row['Player'].'</option>';
```

Comes out to be:

```
<option name="test" value="24,Hulu">Hulu</option>
```

If you wanted to use a form and POST this it would look something like:

```
<?php
 $result = $_POST['test']";
 $value = explode("&&", $result);
 print_r($value);
?>
```

The output of that is:

```
Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => Hulu )
```

Then you can use that array for other parts.